# cytoscapeJS 3.2.5 - get graph object instance - .cytoscape('get')

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I have a question about *cytoscapeJS*. I upgraded my application to use the latest version of cytoscapeJS: *v3.2.5*. In the past, in my code, the network graph was initialised and node/edge data and appearance attributes were set.

Initialisation code changed **from** (the page has an empty `<div>` with `id='cy'`):
`$('#cy').cytoscape({
  container: $('#cy'),
...`

**to**:
`var cy= cytoscape({ // in cytoscapeJS v3.2.5
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
...`

Later on, users could select what layout to use and the code would `get` the graph object and run the selected layout on the *visible* elements as below:

`var cy= $('#cy').cytoscape('get');
var coseLayout= { name: 'cose', handleDisconnected: true, avoidOverlap: true };
cy.$(':visible').layout(coseLayout);`

But the above now throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cytoscape is not a function` (on the first line).

I have gone through the updated website docs (*Core* API, collection, etc.) and demos over the last week but have found no way to do the same in the new cytoscapeJS *3.2.5*, i.e., to ***get*** the graph *outside* the initialisation code and perform some operations on it.

I also posted this query at https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2015 but got no response. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the reference and pass it where need be or keep a global reference.

Comment: Thanks @maxkfranz. Is there no alternative to the old cytoscape('get') method??

Comment: Can you provide a typescript example @maxfranz